# then not called on call method in autobahn js

Tags: callback, autobahn

Then not run in this script. Call function on websocket server running well.

```
// WAMP server
var wsuri = 'ws://localhost:8080';

// connect
ab.connect(wsuri,

   // WAMP session was established
   function (session) {

        // asynchronous RPC, returns promise object
        session.call("hitUp", {
            my : 'data'
        }).then(function(){
            alert('aaaa');
        });

   }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was about websocket server muse be send callResult.

http://wamp.ws/spec/#callresult_message.

If your websocket server dosnt response to client **callResult** .then callback will not be executed.